# Напишите функцию умножения трёх матриц (не пользуйтесь встроенными функциями такими как np.dot(), @)

Tags: python, numpy

Взял за основу код матричного перемножения 2 матриц и доработал для 3 матриц. Пробовал разными способами. Две матрицы перемножает корректно, а на третьей результат не совпадает с проверочным, если использовать @, за исключением последней строчки. Код получился следующий`

```
    import numpy as np
    
    scalar1 = 2 # Создал скаляр
    scalar2 = 7
    scalar3 = 5
    scalar4 = 1
    scalar5 = 1
    vector = np.array([scalar1, scalar2, scalar3, scalar4,scalar5]) # создаю вектор-строку
    vector_vertical = np.array([scalar1, scalar2, scalar3, scalar4, scalar5]).reshape((5,1)) # ветрикальный скаляр
    matrix1=vector*vector_vertical # создаю матрицу
    matrix2=matrix*scalar2  #создаю матрицу
    matrix2=matrix2
    matrix3=matrix1/scalar2  #создаю матрицу
    
        # Функция матричного умножения, принимающая на вход 3 матрицы
def prod_matrix(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3):
  shape1 = matrix1.shape  # определим форму 1-ой матрицы
  shape2 = matrix2.shape  # определим форму 2-ой матрицы
  shape3 = matrix3.shape  # определим форму 3-ей матрицы
  
  if shape1[1] != shape2[0]:  # если количество столбцов 1-ой матрицы не равно количеству строк 2-ой матрицы
    return np.array([])        # тогда умножение невозможно, возвращаем пустой массив
  if shape1[1] != shape3[0]:  # если количество столбцов 1-ой матрицы не равно количеству строк 3-ой матрицы
    return np.array([])        # тогда умножение невозможно, возвращаем пустой массив
  
  out_matrix = np.zeros((shape1[0], shape2[1]))  # создадим матрицу из 0, формой (количество строк 1-ой)Х(количество столбцов 2-ой) матриц
  tot_matrix = np.zeros((shape1[0], shape2[1]))  # создадим матрицу из 0, формой (количество строк 1-ой)Х(количество столбцов 2-ой) матриц
  
  for i in range(shape1[0]):  # пройдемся по индексам строк 1-ой матрицы
    for j in range(shape2[1]):  # пройдемся по индексам столбцов 2-ой матрицы
      curr_cell = 0
      for t in range(shape1[1]):  # пройдемся по индексам стобцов 1-ой матрицы
        curr_cell += matrix1[i,t] * matrix2[t,j]  # посчитаем сумму произведения элементов строки 1-ой матрицы и столбцов 2-ой матрицы
      out_matrix[i,j] = curr_cell  # заменим значения в матрице состоящих из 0, на посчитанную сумму произведений
      shape4 = out_matrix.shape # определим форму полученной матрицы
      for i in range(shape4[0]):  # пройдемся по индексам строк полученной матрицы
        for k in range(shape3[1]):  # пройдемся по индексам столбцов 3-ей матрицы
          curr_celltot = 0
          for j in range(shape4[1]):  # пройдемся по индексам стобцов полученной матрицы
            curr_celltot += out_matrix[i,j] * matrix3[j,k]  # посчитаем сумму произведения элементов строки полученной матрицы и столбцов 3-ей матрицы
            tot_matrix[i,k] = curr_celltot  # заменим значения в матрице состоящих из 0, на посчитанную сумму произведений

return tot_matrix  # вернем полученную матрицу
   
prod_matrix(matrix, matrix1,matrix2)
```

Где искать ошибку? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: ищи ошибку в отступах. я нашел ее там.

Answer (score 7):

На мой вгляд, Вы подошли к решению не с той стороны. А на самом деле, есть гораздо более простой вариант:

```
def prod_matrix_2(matrix1, matrix2):
    . . .
    return result

def prod_matrix_3(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3):
    wrk = prod_matrix_2(matrix1, matrix2)
    return prod_matrix_2(wrk, matrix3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку искать в вашей программе. Но правильно вопрос задать не "где", а "как". Для этих целей существует процесс отладки - надеюсь вам про нее уже рассказывали на уроках.  Если вы работаете в любой IDE -  то используете пошаговое выполнение кода, или режим Debug c точками останова, с проверкой и анализом результатов (состояния переменных программы) на каждом шаге.

Если же по какой-либо причине вы это делать не хотите  -  тогда вставляете в код вывод промежуточных результатов оператором print()  и анализируете результаты после окончания скрипта.

А вообще-то профессия программиста это не написание кода, а на 80% это отладка кода. Так что рекомендую эту премудрость освоить как можно раньше.

Comment: Эти проверки я делал. На этапе перемножения первых двух матриц результат корректен. При умножении на третью идет сбой. Т.е. в последней части кода. При этом в итоговой матрице 4 строки не совпадают, а последняя корректна.

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое "сбой" в программировании и отладке? В какой именно строке идет у вас "сбой" и  какое именно сообщение об ошибке при этом вы получаете от интерпретатора? И проверок нужных вы не делали. Иначе бы вопроса и не было бы. Говорю же -  осваивайте навыки отладки кода. Без этого на работу не возьмут. Никому не нужен программист, не умеющий искать ошибки самостоятельно хотя-бы в своем коде.